# Angular directive model binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have just discovered AngularJS and am in what seems to be a fairly steep learning curve.    Can anyone recommend a couple of good books that will take a "practical" dive into AngularJS.   My programming question is this:

Consider:

```
<input type="text" name="inputField1" ng-model="myModel.firstName" 
       encrypt-and-save="myModel.encryptedFirstName" />
```

In my directive named "encryptAndSave" I want to dynamically bind to the model property whose name (in this case) is "encryptedFirstName".   Everything that I have read seems to say that this is possible, but I haven't found a concrete example of how it is done.   Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jimmy

Here's what I wound up doing.    I discovered $parse and .assign.   I used the $parse at initialization and .assign for late/real-time binding.    Does this make sense, or have I totally missed something?

```
app.directive('encryptAndSave', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var encryptedModelValue = $parse(attrs.encryptAndSave);
            //
            // wait for model change (could also wait for blur??)
            //
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var encrValue = encryptThis(newValue);
                encryptedModelValue.assign(scope, encrValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks again for your help,
Jimmy

Comment: When you have it bound correctly, you should just be using {{encryptedFirstName}} to bind in your markup.

Comment: I like [Angular JS: Novice to Ninja](http://www.amazon.com/AngularJS-Novice-Ninja-Sandeep-Panda/dp/0992279453).

Answer (score 0):

In you directive create isolated scope and use 2 way binding via '='

```
scope: {
      encryptAndSave: '='
    }
```

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myModel = {
    firstName: "joe",
    encryptedFirstName: " encrypted joe"

  };
});

app.directive('encryptAndSave', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      encryptAndSave: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {


      alert(scope.encryptAndSave)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="inputField1" ng-model="myModel.firstName" encrypt-and-save="myModel.encryptedFirstName" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm all about the watchers for this one. The reason is that you can't access dynamic members of the parent scope using an isolated scope. I may be wrong, but it looks like this is what you're trying to do.

```
angular.module("encryptMe", [])
.directive("encryptAndSave", function() {
    function hash(name) {
        return name;
    }

    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("firstName", function() {
                scope[attrs.encryptAndSave] = hash(scope.firstName + "");
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller("encryptController", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "Who?";
});
```

Naturally, you would want to more interesting stuff in your `hash` function. The main thing here is that this directive pays attention to the value passed in when declaring the directive (`encrypt-and-save=[your variable here]`). It then watches the `firstName` variable and updates the given parent-scope variable with the hash of the new value.

Feel free to [try it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/rqtLr5nc/2/).